# Wondering what needs improvement for a specific question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There is this question [What is the official date of resignation when registered mail was delivered on time, but went to a collection point to be picked up the next day?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183123/resignation-and-notice-period) and at the time of my writing it has 4 downvotes and 2 close votes.

The close votes are "needs a lawyer" and while I think any HR person should be able to answer it, I can see that this has some merit. I think it's better to show *why* and at which point it needs a lawyer, but people would need to know how good a German HR education actually is to know whether to vote to close or not.

However, it also has 4 downvotes. Granted, I did some editing for easier language (see edit history), but I think it was clear, conscise, gave all the necessary information, was well tagged... I can seen nothing wrong with it. I don't see how it could have been improved at the core and I don't think we downvoted people for their proficiency with the English language.

So what did I miss? What is so bad about that question?

Comment: The question looks ok to me, downvotes are up to the people who cast them though. They don't have to make sense to anyone else.